# Deleted Ubuntu Partion from dual boot with windows, stuck in grub recovery

Tags: dual-boot, windows, grubrescue

I have attempted using bootrepair from a Ubuntu usb, and lilo neither of which are working. OSrepair states that I have no os on the hard drive yet I know for a fact windows is still on it because when I deleted the Ubuntu partion I did so on my windows os. Now I cant get out of grub rescue and nothing is fixing my bootloader to point to windows and I have zero idea of what to do now.

EDIT: using supergrub2 I was able to boot windows, this is the only way ive been able to do so currently. now I just need to fix my bootloader to point to windows but I'm honestly lost on how to do this

Another edit, since someone tagged this as a dupe, I have already checked any previous posts about this topic for the answer and every thing I have tried hasn't worked. almost as if you who tagged this as a dupe didn't read the first part which said neither boot repair or lilo fixed it. So the other answers will not work.

Comment: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records this might solve your problem, I'm not sure, but it's worth taking a look

Comment: I read it but no bones. Don't have a recovery disk. Or anywhere I could insert a cd for that matter on this computer. All I have is a usb bootable. I really don't know what the issue is with this.

Comment: Bootable usb should work fine, all you need to do is go to Windows cmd and fix boot and mbr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I tried using windows cmd to fix mbr, it didn't work. tried using recovery as well, didn't work. Not sure why either.

Comment: @feline Please read *all* the answers on the duplicate question. Lilo and Boot-Repair are just two options out of many. In this case, OS-Uninstaller might be your best bet (although I've never used it myself, so take this with a grain of salt).

Comment: It's not very useful to just say that a recommendation didn't help. What is useful is to give the outputs of any tools (like the Boot-Repair log file), and what the results were after.

Comment: I tried os-uninstaller as well, it didn't even detect my windows os. Again not sure why any of this is the case. And ill post the log @wjandrea but does that even happen to work on a UEFI boot system? I'm not good with anything to do with boot.

Comment: Boot repair states it was succesful yet it didn't actually work. Heres the boot info log , http://paste.ubuntu.com/24335294/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what I did, but after several attempts at different softwares and, all of them not working. Grub somehow disappeared. I believe It had something to do with rescatux as I went through and selected almost everything I could to see if I could get this os functional without a usb. then after that, I lost grub recovery and instead, gained a windows error screen stating I needed to repair my os. finally it worked when I inserted a windows recovery iso, but some of my files are corrupted for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Go into BIOS and move the windows boot manager to the top using F6 and F7 keys.
Save and exit 
Then you will be able to normally boot into Windows OS

Comment: cant do that, there is no windows boot manager in my bios only the ability to boot from hdd or usb/ sd. I wish it were that simple :'(

Comment: In that case if it is a UEFI boot system then installing the rEFInd bootloader may help but can't tell anything surely

Comment: Hope this documentation related to rEFInd may help http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html